# CSS у класса jumbotron не отображается

Tags: css, asp.net

Стиль класса не изменяется

```
.jumbotron{
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(15, 117, 189, 0.2); 
}
```

Как исправить?

---

```
.jumbotron{
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(15, 117, 189, 0.2); 
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, у вас bootstrap подключается после того, как вы переопределили его стиль.

Comment: Добавьте что-то в таком роде: `color: #fff !important`.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос `html-код` страницы, где будет видно, где присоединяется ваш bootstrap-файл, и где у вас идет переопределение стиля. Потому что сейчас почти любой ответ будет равносилен "ткнуть пальцем в небо".